# AES CBC algorithm/padding in java/angular

Tags: java, angular, algorithm, aes, cbc-mode

I have written this code in Angular to encrypt a string:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
  })
export class CryptoService {
  
  encrypt(message: string, clef: string): string {

    const salt = CryptoJS.SHA256("123456789123");

    const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(clef, salt, {
      keySize: 128 / 32,
      iterations: 1000
  });

    // var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(clef);
    let iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(clef);
    let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(message.toString()), key,
    {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });


    // var encryptedMessage = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message.trim(), key).toString();

    return encrypted.toString();
  }

  generateKey(): string {
      let result = '';
      const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
      const charactersLength = characters.length;
      let counter = 0;
      while (counter < 16) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
      counter += 1;
      }
      return result;
  }
}
```

I transfer my key and encriptedMessage to the back for the decryption.

I code dat on java:

```
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;

public class AESUtilService {
    
    protected static final String salt = "123456789123";
    
    public SecretKey getKeyFromPassword(String password)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 1000, 128/32);
        SecretKey secret = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        return secret;
    }
    public String decrypt(String cipherText, SecretKey key)
        throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException,
        BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
            
        String algorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("MnTQLHcWumIKTXpQ".getBytes());
        
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText));
        return new String(plainText);
    }
    
}
```

My issue is the following.
The part of the code `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);` crashes in java, if I use `String algorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";`
However it would pass with `String algorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";`, but this time it's angular that would crash. **padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs5**

I can't find a solution for this problem, and that's why I ask for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code seems like, There is a issue with your PBEKeySpec and key length specification.
**JAVA**: you must need to use "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" instead of "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding"
**Angular**: Make changes on key length and PBEKeySpec
let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("hasan test"), key,
{
keySize: 16,
iv: iv,
mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
}).toString();

Answer (score 0):

I finaly find a post who sayd they pkcs5 in java are the same as pkcs7 in angular
-->padding (128)

source:
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding